# Find nearest ancestor/sibling that matches criteria

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML that is composed of container nodes holding various child nodes including other container nodes. Sample XML would look like...

```
<CONTAINER>
    <SEARCHFOR />
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <CONTAINER>
        <SEARCHFOR />
        <ITEM/>
        <ITEM/>
        <CONTAINER>
            <SEARCHFOR />
            <ITEM id="1" />
            <ITEM/>
            <ITEM/>
            <CONTAINER>
                <ITEM id="2" />
            </CONTAINER>
        </CONTAINER>
    </CONTAINER>
</CONTAINER>
```

I'd like to find the SEARCHFOR node that is nearest (in scope) to the ITEM having id=2. The SEARCHFOR node can be a preceding-sibling of ITEM or a child of an ancestor CONTAINER node. I have an XPath expression that can locate all SEARCHFOR nodes that are in scope that match the criteria, but I can't seem to get it to only return the single element that is nearest.

```
//ITEM[@id="2"]/ancestor::CONTAINER/SEARCHFOR
```

I am testing in Sketchpath and will be implementing this in Delphi using an XML parser that can handle XPath 2.0 so that syntax is also acceptable. I can do this in code by getting my results and using Delphi to get the one of interest, but if at all possible I really need this to be done within the XPath itself for my implementation. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this XPath 2.0 expression answers your question :

```
(//ITEM[@id='2']/(ancestor::CONTAINER/SEARCHFOR|preceding-sibling::SEARCHFOR))[last()]
```

It works by building a sequence of elements in document order, then it chooses the last one, which is, given your description, the nearest (if I get you right).

Comment: Most excellent. Thanks. For my simple example this is perfect and should fit into my 20+ line xpath I'm really working on just fine. Ughhh! My brain is all, but fried right now.

Answer (score 1):

The `preceding` axis searches in reverse document order, so selecting the first such preceding element works as expected (as long as we can assume that `SEARCHFOR` elements aren't themselves an ancestor of the target `ITEM`):

```
(//ITEM[@id='2']/preceding::SEARCHFOR[parent::CONTAINER])[1]
```

Can we also assume that `SEARCHFOR` elements are always in a `CONTAINER`? If so, then we don't need that explicit check, making it even shorter:

```
(//ITEM[@id='2']/preceding::SEARCHFOR)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works for the sample and I'll try to remember this for future reference, but in my real-world application my xpath is significantly more complex as is the XML and the first suggestion above requires less characters.