# Obtain unique result set using absolute path of nodes (or similar) as key

Tags: xml, xpath, unique

I have XML that looks like the following.

```
<CONTAINER>
    <SEARCHFOR />
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <ITEM/>
    <CONTAINER>
        <SEARCHFOR />
        <ITEM/>
        <ITEM/>
        <CONTAINER>
            <SEARCHFOR />
            <ITEM id="1" />
            <ITEM/>
            <ITEM/>
            <CONTAINER>
                <ITEM id="2" />
            </CONTAINER>
        </CONTAINER>
    </CONTAINER>
</CONTAINER>
```

I am looking for the SEARCHFOR nodes that are closest in scope to the ITEM nodes. See my other question for what I mean here.

[Find nearest ancestor/sibling that matches criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506525/find-nearest-ancestor-sibling-that-matches-criteris)

I need to locate ITEM nodes of interest first and then work up from there for the SEARCHFOR nodes. In other words, //SEARCHFOR as my expression is not sufficient. I have an expression which locates the SEARCHFOR node closest in scope to each ITEM node. This works well and looks like...

```
for $v in 
    //ITEM       
return 
    ($v/(ancestor::CONTAINER/SEARCHFOR|preceding-sibling::SEARCHFOR))[last()]
```

However, the list of results is not unique. I receive 11 results, one for each ITEM node as expected. I'd like a unique result set containing only 3 items. I've seen suggestions on here to use grouping in XSL, but I can't do this with the tools I'm using, but I can use XPath 2.0 syntax. I've also seen the use of normalize-space() to get unique results, but I don't have any text with my XML. My uniqueness needs to be determined by the absolute path of each node.

Thanks for any assistance,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well select only those ITEM elements you are interested in (i.e. those having a SEARCHFOR): `ITEM[
    (ancestor::CONTAINER/SEARCHFOR|preceding-sibling::SEARCHFOR)[last()]
  ]/(ancestor::CONTAINER/SEARCHFOR|preceding-sibling::SEARCHFOR)[last()]`. Or simply add a step `/.` to what you have e.g. `(for $v in 
    //ITEM

return 
    ($v/(ancestor::CONTAINER/SEARCHFOR|preceding-sibling::SEARCHFOR))[last()])/.`, that should eliminate any duplicates.